# How to replace a specific string in Java?

Tags: java, string, replace

I usually don't ask for help but here I really need it.
I have the following code  example:

```
String text = "aa aab aa aab";
text = text.replace("aa", "--");
System.out.println(text);

Console output: -- --b -- --b
```

I have a question, how do I only replace **aa** parts of the string not **aab** included.

So the console output is:

```
-- aab -- aab
```

I have another example:

```
String text = "111111111 1";
text = text.replace("1", "-");
System.out.println(text);

Console output: --------- -
```

I only want to replace a single character, not all the same ones who are placed together.
So the console output is:

```
111111111 -
```

Are there any Java shortcuts for situations like these? I can't figure it out, how to only replace specific part of the string. 
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a *regular expression* with `String.replaceAll(String, String)`. By using word boundaries (`\b`), something like

```
String[] texts = { "aa aab aa aab", "111111111 1" };
String[] toReplace = { "aa", "1" };
String[] toReplaceWith = { "--", "-" };
for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
    String text = texts[i];
    text = text.replaceAll("\\b" + toReplace[i] + "\\b", toReplaceWith[i]);
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
-- aab -- aab
111111111 -
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex

```
String text = "111111111 1";
text = text.replaceAll("1(?=[^1]*$)", "");
System.out.println(text);
```

Explanation:

- `String.replaceAll` takes a regex contrarily to `String.replace` which takes a litteral to replace
- `(?=reg)` the right part of the regex must be followed by a string matching the regex `reg`, but only the right part will be captured
- `[^1]*` means a sequence from 0 to any number of characters different from `'1'`
- `$` means the end of the string is reached

In plain english, this means: *Please replace by an empty string all the occurrences of the `'1'` character followed by any number of characters different from `'1'` until the end of the string*.

Comment: Looking at other answers, I may have misunderstood the question. Keeping for the record

Answer (score 0):

We can use the StringTokenizer present in Java to acheive the solution for any kind of input. Below is the sample solution,

public class StringTokenizerExample {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "aa aab aa aab";
    String output = "";
    String replaceWord = "aa";
    String replaceWith = "--";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input," ");
    System.out.println("Before Replace: "+input);
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        String word = st.nextElement().toString();
        if(word.equals(replaceWord)){
            word = replaceWith;
            if(st.hasMoreElements()){
                word = " "+word+" ";
            }else{
                word = " "+word;
            }
        }
        output = output+word;
    }
    System.out.println("After Replace: "+output);
}
```